# How to give up power-up bought by unicoins?

Tags: support, unicoins

I bought some Stack Overflow power-ups. Now I change my mind and do not want some of them, how to give them up? With or without refund :-)

Comment: Go to sleep and they will be gone the next day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open the dialog box
2. Select the powerup you wish to give up
3. Click "Recycle Now," which costs 10 Unicoins.

Note: There is no refund, and you are charged 10 Unicoins to remove the powerup.

Comment: It is strange. I cannot see that recycle button before I ask, but now I can see it.

Comment: I don't see any "recycle now" button.

Comment: @JustinMorgan please refresh your page.. it is a quick fix which is done just now.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I thought it was part of the joke.

Comment: I did not get a refund :(

Comment: @Rotem Updated.

Comment: @Mooseman I actually checked :( (Oh, you mean updated the answer. I thought you mean my refund was updated :))

Answer (score 3):

Go to the 'Buy Powers' tab, then click on the power-up you don't want anymore. You can recycle it for 10 Unicoins